# please explain about this line of code a[s1.charAt(i) - 'a']++;

Tags: java

I am doing a java program but can't understand how it works this line of code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++)
    a[s1.charAt(i) - 'a']++;
```

Answer (score 9):

`s1.charAt(i)` returns the `i`'th character of the `String` s1.
**Assuming that this String contains only lower case letters (i.e. 'a' to 'z')**, `s1.charAt(i)-'a'` maps the character 'a' to index 0, 'b' to index 1, and so on ('z' is mapped to index 25).

```
a[s1.charAt(i)-'a']++;
```

increments a counter that corresponds with the character `s1.charAt(i)`.

Therefore, this loop counts the number of occurrences of each letter in the `String` `s1`.

In the end, `a[0]` will contain the number of 'a's, `a[1]` the number of 'b's and so on.

Comment: But will fail horribly if the string doesn't consist of the lower alphabet :)

Comment: @Lino true that

Comment: better convert the string to lowercase first.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal will not work, see this: `".!'3£$".toLowerCase().equals(".!'3£$")`

Comment: Just a short clarification about the `.charAt(i)-'a'`: mathematical operations on characters will use [their decimal unicode values](https://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm), so `'c' - 'a'` is indeed `2` as explained above, but that's because `'c' - 'a'` becomes `99 - 97 = 2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++)//This line represents loop from 0 to length of s1-1
        a[s1.charAt(i)-'a']++;
//s1.chatAt(i) returns the character presents at ith index.
//s1.chatAt(i)-'a' returns (ASCII value of s1.charAt(i) - ASCII value of 'a')
```

Comment: we can give like this also??  a[s1.chart(i) -'b']++;

Comment: It calculates the number of occurrences of lower case letters.